# Power Automate flow triggerede by "When a row is added, modified or deleted" runs double when record have child records

Tags: powerapps, power-automate, dataverse

I'm using the "When a row is added, modified or deleted" trigger in at Power Automate flow to get records, when it's a approved by a certain user:

[image]

The flow runs fine, but when the record has child records, the flow runs twice.

I've checked the output on the double runs and they are exact the same.

In the screenshot the first run is on a record, which have no child records and the next two runs is on a record that has child records.

[image]

I would like the flow to only run once eventhough there are child records attached to the main records.
Or to find some kind of work around.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.

It was a question of using the column filter (Select columns) and adding that column I wanted to use as the only triggering column.

The settings of the "When a row is added, modified or deleted" now looks like this:

[Updated settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCw4q.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar issue where two separate updates happened so close to each other that they ended up triggering the OnUpdate flow twice, even though the Filter Rows condition wasn't satisfied at the time of the first update.

This seems to happen because of the async nature of the flow trigger.
If the second update runs before the first trigger is evaluated, then it can read the new state of the entity and end up firing.

Like Mikkel suggested, one solution is to add Select columns.
If feasible, I would suggest moving to a synchronous plugin.